# Strange plot artifacts when plotting the underdamped oscialltor solution

Tags: plotting, numerical-value

I'm plotting something trivial; the solution to an underdamped harmonic oscilator:
$$x(t) = A_{0} \cos(\omega t) e^{-t/\tau}$$
In MM speak I say:
`xOft[A0_, v_, T_, t_] = A0 Cos[2 Pi v t] Exp[-t/T]`

Plotting with:
`Plot[xOft[1.4*10^-8, 29616123, 441, t],{t,0,1000}]` produces,
[image]

Can anyone explain why MM produces such a strange plot for such a simple function? In the example above I scaled the $y$-axis with $10^{8}$ to check if it was a scaling issue...seemingly not.
I want to make sure that this model is stable in MM before I do other things to it.

So I'd like to check:

- If this is just a plot issue, why and how can we get rid of it?
- If it is a real representation of the function, why is MM producing this result?

Thanks

Comment: Moiré-effect. Increase `PlotPoints`.

Comment: And `MaxRecursion` option: `MaxRecursion -> 12, PlotPoints -> 100`

Comment: Thanks for both answers! If you have time could one of you add an answer with a short explanation so I can accept and assign credit?

Comment: It is acceptable on this forum to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xOft[A0_, v_, T_, t_] = A0 Cos[2 Pi v t] Exp[-t/T];
```

The artifacts that you observed are due to the function being under-sampled in the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). You can increase the sampling by increasing the number of initial sampling points ([`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html)) and increasing the maximum number of recursive subdivisions that can be used ([`MaxRecursions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursions.html)). These increases will naturally slow down the plotting.

```
Plot[xOft[1.4*10^-8, 29616123, 441, t], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 12, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Or interactively,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[xOft[1.4*10^-8, 29616123, 441, t], {t, 0, 1000},
  MaxRecursion -> mr, PlotPoints -> pp],
 {{pp, 100, PlotPoints},
  {Automatic, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 500}},
 {{mr, 12, MaxRecursion},
  {Automatic, Range[5, 15]} // Flatten}]
```